# struts html:link custom attribute

Tags: jsp, struts

I'm trying to use Apache Struts with BootStrap css which uses the custom css attibute `data-toggle="dropdown"` for its menus.

I tried with

```
<html:link action="/Home" styleClass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <bean:message key="menu.person" />
</html:link>
```

However `data-toggle="dropdown"` is not allowed, in NetBeans it gives error:

```
Attribute data-toggle invalid for tag link according to TLD
```

How do I put a custom property like `data-toggle` inside an `<html:link>`?

So far I can see only id and class properties are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

What version? IIRC later versions of S1 allow arbitrary attributes, but I'd have to double-check.

If you cannot upgrade, extract the TLD and modify it to allow arbitrary attributes under JSP 2.0:

```
<dynamic-attributes>true</dynamic-attributes>
```

Comment: I have Apache Struts 1, I'm quite sure it isn't allowed because NetBeans complains immediately when I put the data-toggle attribute. I looked inside the TLD file however have no idea how to put a css parameter in there!

Comment: @dendini **Which version of Struts 1?** I *know* it isn't allowed for your version, that's why you asked the question, and why I provided the answers: upgrade, or modify the TLD.

Comment: I cannot upgrade an entire project from struts 1 to struts 2 just for this tiny bit. I will certainly in a future. For now can you indicate a tld modification to add a custom parameter like data-toggle?

Comment: @dendini I didn't say *anything* about Struts 2. I asked **which version of Struts 1**.

Comment: you said "upgrade", considering I am using Struts 1 that sounds like upgrading to Struts 2.

Comment: @dendini It's why I asked which version of S1, because upgrading your version of S1 may provide the functionality you need without you having to do anything.

Comment: sorry I got it.. I have Struts 1.3.10 which apparently is the latest stable release of Struts 1 :(

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you expand on this answer a bit? Where in the TLD does this tag? Thanks.