# Is there a way to put html data attribute on struts html:link tag?

Tags: html, jsp, struts, anchor, struts-1

I have a problem where I cannot put analytic code on my struts `html:link` tag. The code won't render if I put a `data-analytics` attribute on like this:

```
<html:link styleClass="analytics-click"
           action="${globalSites_context}${forgotPasswordAction}"
           title="${forgotPasswordLink}"
           data-analytics='{"location":"BrandBar","description":"BrandBar forget password"}'>${forgotPasswordLink}
</html:link>
```

What can I do?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166664/struts-htmllink-custom-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code to plain HTML

```
<a class="analytics-click"
   href="${globalSites_context}${forgotPasswordAction}"
   title="${forgotPasswordLink}"
   data-analytics='{"location":"BrandBar","description":"BrandBar forget password"}'>${forgotPasswordLink}
</a>
```